# Interpretation of Inner Product in a two-tower model

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning

I have seen at quite a few places the use of two-tower architecture. [This](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2002.05515.pdf)(Fig 6) is one of the examples. Each tower computes embedding of a concept which is orthogonal to the concepts in the rest of the towers. Also, I have seen that the next step on getting an n-dimensional embedding from the towers an inner product is taken to measure Cosine similarity.

I would like to know how to interpret this Inner Product. The two n-dimensional embeddings represents different concepts. What is the meaning of similarity here ?